# Substring between two indices

Tags: php, string, substring

The objective of my program: To split a big string, into an array of strings, each of which contains the segment of text between the substring "zone", and the next occurence of this same substring.

What I tried:

```
#Get file into a string
$filecont=file_get_contents($filename);
#Count all occurences of the substring, and get the positions of the substring into the array $arr
$arr=strallpos($filecont,"zone",0);
#The function strallpos does its job. The array $arr is now:
#Array ( [0] => 70 [1] => 148 [2] => 197 [3] => 316 [4] => 500 [5] => 637 [6] => 709 [7] => 748 [8] => 867 [9] => 878 [10] => 940 [11] => 990 [12] => 1154 [13] => 1321 [14] => 1440 [15] => 1561 [16] => 1684 [17] => 1695 [18] => 1759 [19] => 1811 [20] => 1926 [21] => 2045 [22] => 2168 [23] => 2285 )
#Find and return the substring
for ($i=0;($i+1)<=count($arr);$i++)
{       
    #Line 53 follows
    print (substr ($filecont,$arr($i),($arr($i+1)-$arr($i))));      
}
```

The error I get is: `Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\wamp\www\dns.php on line 53`

What am I doing wrong? I'd like some pointers on the error code.

Comment: Do you try to get the string or the position of the string?

Comment: I got the position of the substring already, in the form of the array, $arr, each of its values contain the positions of occurence of string. Now I'm trying to return the segments of string between these positions.

Comment: `()` invokes functions, `[]` accesses array indicies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems to be that you need to use explode, as in:

```
$zones = explode("zone", $filecont);
```

This will store an array in $zones containing all the strings in between the words 'zone'. Try and tell if it worked :)